# The following classes could not be found: android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

What causes the following error in the layout preview in Android Studio?

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
>   Tip: Try to build the project.

Comment: closed as off-topic? seriously? Those who voted to close this definitely don't understand the question at all.

Answer (score 273):

The Actionbar has been deprecated and replaced by Toolbar.  That being said, you can do the following if you want to continue using Actionbar for now:

1. Open styles.xml in the values folder inside the res folder.
2. Add the word *Base* to the beginning of the theme name so that it reads "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

[image]

I had the same issue today and this solution worked for me. FYI I am in Android Studio though, but hopefully,the solution is similar for Eclipse.

FYI here is a decent blog post on replacing the Actionbar with the Toolbar for when you are ready to do so: https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/

Comment: I got this error just creating a new default project in Android Studio. This solved it.

Comment: if "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" doesnt work you should try "Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" because it's work for me... :) (android studio 3.0.1)

Answer (score 46):

I think you must be depending on `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"` in your `module` settings.

`ActionBar` has been deprecated.

Just change your dependencies from `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` to `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'` in **"build.gradle"**.

You can also change your style parent to `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`.

Try to use the `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar`.

Answer (score 32):

**This one works for me**

Changing AppTheme parent in res/values/styles.xml resolved this problem. Replace

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Or you can change **API level 21** from list.

Comment: That works but what is it exactly doing when you put Base.Theme?

Comment: Android had introduce toolbar in place of Action bar which is the cause of this error but by changing it to Base.Theme  you are simply solving the problem. By default it does not change it self (in current version of Android Studio) so we have to do manually.   You can also go through others answer which also tells you the same thing.  Sorry i was busy in project so can't reply fast.

Answer (score 9):

goto: res-->values-->styles(V21)-->

**Code**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

select your theme as `Apptheme.NoActionBar` in **preview**. Because `ActionBar` is depricated, welcome back to `ToolBar`. NO need to change your dependencies in `build.gradle(Module:app)`.
from `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1`.

Hope this will help you!!!

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue, and as many have said since ActionBar has been deprecated the trick was to specify

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

NOTE: that the parent ends in .NoActionBar.

Since ActionBar has been deprecated Android has gone into using ToolBar which you can read about here on the [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

I tried specifying

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

As a another post stated and that threw errors. Though others may not have that issue.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem in Android Studio 1.5 (even with AppCompatActivity), and my attempt to solve the problem was to update my Android Studio to 2.0. It solves the problem in my case. You can found the link download in: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest

Comment: Besides, Android Studio 2.0 has instant run which is very cool in my opinion. My code instantly updates in my device. You should really try this out.

Comment: Just want to add this issue has been fixed in Android Studio 1.5.1
[Issue 194975 - android - Spurious warning: WindowDecorActionBar not found - Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker - Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194975)

Answer (score 3):

thanks @joshgoldeneagle, worked in AS v1.4 for me. also effective in AS is to open "build.gradle (Module.app)" and change version from v7.23.1.1 to v7.23.0.1 -hth

Answer (score 2):

#### Quick fix

Select a theme with no AtcionBar in UI Preview Tool 
[image: Pick image button]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change the api rendering level to 17, there may be rendering problem with higher level apis, might be higher level apis suppose to have a default theme, and hope you are not specified none.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For AS v1.4 adding "Base" before Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar in the styles.xml folder solved the problem

Additionally, updating to AS v2.1 also solved the problem. Which is better likely depends on collaborators and their AS version.

Answer (score 0):

In res/values/styles.xml, you will find your AppTheme as below :-

Change it to :-

by adding "Base" the rendering issue will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the theme in the manifest solved my problem.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```