# Rendering Error: The following classes could not be found

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio

I am a complete noob to java and android studio and I was wondering if someone could help me with my school project.
When I start a new project in android studio, It gives me this error:
Rendering Problem
The following classes could not be found:

```
android.support.v4.internal.app.windowdecoractionbar
```

[image]

Comment: Similar problem - you can find a solution [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742114/rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-support-v7)!