# Rendering issue while using action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, rendering, android-appbarlayout, appcompatactivity

When I write the following code in the `onCreate` method :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

        // Enable the Up button
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setTitle("Vodafone-Dongles");
    }
}
```

I get:

[image: click here for image description]

Otherwise it is OK and shows the default title of the action bar.

Why am I getting it?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742114/rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-support-v7

Comment: Please share the xml layout

Answer (score 0):

You should use Toolbar instead of Actionbar:-

insert in your activity:-

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

include following in layout:-

```
    <Include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" ></Include>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```