# The following classes could not be found: Names of layouts

Tags: java, android, xml

I must to compose screen by an template. 
There are 4 simple-text fields, 4 text input fields and 7 different buttons. At this moment I does't reached to buttons, becouse when I trying to Build my project, Android Studio gives out an next Warning :

```
Missing classes:
The following classes could not be found:
- Description (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- Desease (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- InputDescription (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- InputDesease (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- InputLocation (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- InputName (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- Location (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- Name (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

I read articles about the same problem here,
[The following classes could not be found: android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742114/the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-support-v7-internal-app-window) 
As I understand, here I must to declare the right class. But I don't understand what I should do with this problem? Why A.S. says that my textViews are classes?
2 xml files are presented below:
First is MainActivity, with all layouts , in second xml is actoinbar, where I want to centrilize my app name.

MainActivity XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
       android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.boris_veriga.home_screen.MainActivity">

    <Name
        android:id="@+id/person_Name"
        tools:text="@string/textView_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />


    <InputName
        android:id="@+id/inputName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/input_yourName"

        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/person_Name" />



    <Desease
        android:id="@+id/person_Desease"
        tools:text="@string/textView_desease"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />

    <InputDesease
        android:id="@+id/inputDesease"
        android:hint="@string/input_yourDesease"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/person_Desease"

        android:inputType="textPersonName" />



    <Location
        android:id="@+id/person_Location"
        tools:text="@string/textView_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp" />

    <InputLocation
        android:id="@+id/inputLocation"
        android:hint="@string/input_yourLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/person_Location"

        android:inputType="textPersonName" />



    <Description
        android:id="@+id/person_Description"
        tools:text="@string/textView_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp" />

    <InputDescription
        android:id="@+id/inputDescription"
        android:hint="@string/input_yourDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/person_Description"

        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

ActionBar - XML(I want to set app title in center):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ActionBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</android.support.constraint.LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity - .java:

```
package com.example.boris_veriga.home_screen;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

P.S.:Sory for my English and I'm new in Android. Thank'u!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `InputName`, `InputLocation` etc?
You can use [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) for input and [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) for the text.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I thought that I can add my own name for layouts.